# MQTT subscription topic match

Tags: code-golf, string, decision-problem, parsing

## Background

MQTT (Message Queuing Telemetry Transport) is an ISO standard publish-subscribe-based messaging protocol ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MQTT)).

Each message has a topic, such as the following examples:

- `myhome/groundfloor/livingroom/temperature`
- `USA/California/San Francisco/Silicon Valley`
- `5ff4a2ce-e485-40f4-826c-b1a5d81be9b6/status`
- `Germany/Bavaria/car/2382340923453/latitude`

MQTT clients may subscribe to message topics using wildcards:

- Single level: `+`
- All levels onward: `#`

For example, the subscription `myhome/groundfloor/+/temperature` would produce these results (non-conformances in **bold**):

✅ myhome/groundfloor/livingroom/temperature
✅ myhome/groundfloor/kitchen/temperature
❌ myhome/groundfloor/livingroom/**brightness**
❌ myhome/**firstfloor**/livingroom/temperature
❌ **garage**/groundfloor/**fridge**/temperature

Whereas the subscription `+/groundfloor/#` would produce these results:

✅ myhome/groundfloor/livingroom/temperature
✅ myhome/groundfloor/kitchen/brightness
✅ garage/groundfloor/fridge/temperature/more/specific/fields
❌ myhome/**firstfloor**/livingroom/temperature
❌ myhome/**basement**/corner/temperature

More info [here](https://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-essentials-part-5-mqtt-topics-best-practices/).

## The Task

Implement a function/program accepting two strings and returning a boolean. The first string is the subject topic, the second is the criteria topic. The criteria topic uses the subscription syntax detailed above. The function is truthy when the subject matches the criteria.

Rules for this task:

- Topics are ASCII
- There are no criteria fields beyond the `#` wildcard
- Wildcards do not appear in subject topics
- Number of subject fields >= number of criteria fields
- There are no 0-character fields nor leading or tailing forward slashes

## Test cases

criteria1 = "myhome/groundfloor/+/temperature"
criteria2 = "+/groundfloor/#"

("abc", "ab") => false
("abc", "abc") => true
("abc/de", "abc") => false
("myhome/groundfloor/livingroom/temperature", criteria1) => true
("myhome/groundfloor/kitchen/temperature", criteria1) => true
("myhome/groundfloor/livingroom/brightness", criteria1) => false
("myhome/firstfloor/livingroom/temperature", criteria1) => false
("garage/groundfloor/fridge/temperature", criteria1) => false
("myhome/groundfloor/livingroom/temperature", criteria2) => true
("myhome/groundfloor/kitchen/brightness", criteria2) => true
("garage/groundfloor/fridge/temperature/more/specific/fields", criteria2) => true
("myhome/firstfloor/livingroom/temperature", criteria2) => false
("myhome/basement/corner/temperature", criteria2) => false
("music/kei$ha/latest", "+/kei$ha/+") => true

Comment: @HyperNeutrino, that's a good question. I'm on the fence. Subject `a/b/c` would not match criteria `a/b`, so I'm inclined to say **No**.

Comment: Are /, + and # guaranteed never to appear in topic parts?

Comment: I see in the blog linked that "Additionally, the forward slash alone is a valid topic" but no mention of + and #, so I guess these two can be.

Comment: @JonathanAllan From http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc398718106 : The wildcard characters can be used in Topic Filters, but MUST NOT be used within a Topic Name

Comment: @NickKennedy - nice digging, but we really shouldn't need to.

Comment: Can I return not boolean, but result which have unambiguous cast to it and can be used in binary evaluation?

Comment: Also, important note from linked blog: `#` can be only last character and must preceded by `/`.

Comment: @Patrick: Can you add the following test cases (subject, criteria, output): (`music/kei$ha/latest`, `+/kei$ha/+`, truthy); (`abc`,`ab`, falsey), (`abc/de`, `abc`, falsey).

Comment: Don't forget the rule that subscriptions to `#` should not match topics that start with `$sys/` (topics that show internal state of the broker) or `$shared/` (topics used for shared subscription groups)

Comment: Hi, @hardillb, I had specifically excluded this rule, and adding it now would cause a lot of rewrites of answers.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 72 bytes

```python
lambda a,b:bool(re.match(b.translate({43:"[^/]+",35:".+"}),a))
import re
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##xZHLSsRAEEX38xVNu0lImCxGNwMu3PgF7nxAd1JJCvtFVUUYxG@PLSjMyDhGEdz0ouCevo@0kzGGzdxf3s3OeNsZZWq7tTG6gmDtjbRjYddCJrAzAsXz@Warbx@a@0rXm4utXlf6paxNWa7Qp0iiCGaeLLeESTAGdam0343RQzNQnELXuxipqRoBn4CMTAR6tTLMQFLc0AQKWfXFMZHDJwz5EP2Bulb7H2Yni2CPmKNBOE36QF0bx8uMWcJhlADMX/o6AuuRWH4Vch82GDLDobOesMun0yE/71UdIM7@dZ4Ffe6BFjXQ@JgfTtBij23uHlzHP9r@b@Z6h1nD4CFI00YKQN9slQiDFPrKOdVmIav0Ru50Ob8C)

This problem can be trivially simplified to a regex match, though another more interesting method may produce better results.

EDIT I came up with a 107-byte solution not using regex. I don't know if it can get shorter than 72 or maybe I'm just not seeing to correct approach to this. Just the split-zip structure seems to be too large though. [Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##xZO/TsMwEMZ3nuLkLrEaNQMbUgYWnoANGBzHTk44tnXnoIaXDw4C1KJSAkJisc5nfb/788lxSn3wl7Ot72enhqZVoMrmSjlXTHUtNiJQISrhQwL0sAflW5hyeLcvxVY8SBsI9uWSgWeMhdpxdJgWSdnsdBj9ayxlvn28SClnHhvWhDFh8FCDGKY@DKbqKEta60KgalslM0RDKo1kxMWFYjaUilsaDSCDLU6JHD6hz4kwHKlLOCwo5TrYIybdG3@e9I66UY7XNdYQdn3yhvnLvk7ALBKnXw15COsUqe64M0vY5tT5IT/7tT1CbP7VnhX7PACt2kA1hHxwNBot6rx741r@kfd/Y9cbrFFsBuNTpQN5Q994FQmXb3ftHOgsZIgLuRVyfgE)

Comment: If the sequence contains any other regex characters, this might fail. I'd look out for that even though none of the current test cases contain anything remotely regex-like.

Comment: ...like `f('myhome/ground$floor/livingroom/temperature', 'myhome/ground$floor/+/temperature')` which fails

Comment: As Value Ink says, `+/kei$ha/+` does not match `music/kei$ha/latest`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 20 bytes

```
ṣ€”/ZṖF”#eƊ¿œiÐḟ”+ZE
```

A monadic Link accepting a list of lists of characters, `[topic, pattern]`, which returns `1` or `0` for match or no-match respectively.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzsWPmtY8apirH/Vw5zQ3IEM59VjXof1HJ2cenvBwx3yggHaU6////9XTE4sS01P104vyS/NS0nLy84v004oyU4BCJam5BalFiSWlRan6uflAorggNTkzLTNZPy0zNSelWF1HQV1bXxumXFkdAA)** Or see a [test-suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzsWPmtY8apirH/Vw5zQ3IEM59VjXof1HJ2cenvBwx3yggHaU639voKKjew63AykQM/L//@ho9dzKjPzcVP30ovzSvJS0nPz8Iv2czLLMPKBAfq5@SWpuQWpRYklpUaq6jgI2xdooamK5dLAamZ1ZkpyRmkc185CcmFSUmZ5RkpdaXEyyiWmZRcUl1PFzemJRYjqqqrSizBSgEA28jGakNoo6ZYKRgBpiWHUT5R393HwgUVyQmpyZlpkMDM3UnJRiQg4iKszxGZCUWJyam5pXop@cX5SXWkRYaywA).

#### How?

```
ṣ€”/ZṖF”#eƊ¿œiÐḟ”+ZE - Link: list of lists of characters, [topic, pattern]
 €                   - for each:
ṣ                    -   split at occurrences of:
  ”/                 -     '/' character
    Z                - transpose (any excess of topic is kept)
           ¿         - while...
          Ɗ          - ...condition: last three links as a monad:
       ”#            -   '#' character
         e           -   exists in:
      F              -     flatten
     Ṗ               - ...do: pop the tail off
              Ðḟ     - filter discard those for which:
            œi       -   first multi-dimensional index of: ([] if not found, which is falsey)
                ”+   -     '+' character
                  Z  - transpose
                   E - all equal?
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 65 bytes

Regex solution. I added `Regex.escape` in case a criteria name just so happens to be something like `com.java/string[]/\n` or something silly that would have regex pieces.

```ruby
->s,c{s=~/^#{Regexp.escape(c).sub('\#','.*').gsub'\+','[^/]*'}$/}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY9RbsMgDED/ewrabKJtMjhBdoj9pqlEiCGoDUQYtlVpdvWMSpOWSpX6YSGb52fbx@Yyq3J@e8dCjlj@8GM2foCG74EBSjHAVu4YxmZLDxktKNvTHdMpp4c8pdWR13s6vfBpfv2qVoT0l871wLV30bbq7JznZ/NpbCq4ngfoB/AiRA@P2ZMJsgP7HFxIG290Fywg/qPKeAxPxmvhhb63Km/aVFpyNQMhO9I6csVr6hpiQHKblO59sFe@bCb53V@2cMmb68@2ISQb5UTK9KzXqsKCyHraJABsu0ox/wI)

Non-regex solution, 77 bytes

Uses a nice simple split, zip, and match technique. I developed this one first before realizing that even with `Regex.escape` the regex solution would've been shorter anyways.

```ruby
->s,c{s.split(?/).zip(c.split ?/).all?{|i,j|i==j||'+#'[j||9]||!j&&c[-1]==?#}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY/BboMwDIbvfQqvaG0nKGjHHTIeBHFIQwJmIUFJWNUSnp0GddKoVKkHy/Lv359tM5wusyDz8dsmbLSp7SW6Q559pFfsD@xew1JTKfPRY9J6JKT1fh9H@yLkr9L7t3a3Y8XxsyQkj6Zpfj8XG4Du0uiOZ7XRg6qE1NpkEn9RBUF3meNdzw11g@HPvT/oWMPVa@MKejJYN05xa/@tAo11L9bX1ND6kSoMVkFa@8qUU9ZApcFbH6b6wVlYNoV/n9wVr4chfuhFKxZbWH@0LUA0sglISKKwCbBy2oY2V9UmxHwD)

Comment: `.*?` should work in place of `[^/]*`.

Comment: @NicHartley that will trigger a false match for criteria `a/+/d` with topic `a/b/c/d`

Comment: Ah, so it will. Wrapping that in an atomic group fixes that, but then it's two bytes longer. Oh well.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-pl`, 50 bytes

```perl
$_="\Q$_";s|\\\+|[^/]+|g;s/\\\#/.*/;$_=<>=~m|^$_$|
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcoxDgIhEEDR3mPsUkl0Kitc72AtLjERVxJgyMCamEw8uiOt5X/5xVM8iCg3Dfas3GAqW2s1X2a4al5MhZ4j7Ldg@nM8TZ/Es3KKRTQshGu@PyIiwbhJ7ycm/4cxvELugAmaT8XTra3kv1hawFxlV@IP)

Comment: small improvement, `<>=~/^$_$/` at the end

Answer (score 1):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), <s>107</s> <s>91</s> <s>76</s> <s>65</s> 102 bytes

An anonymous function, returns subject topic as truthy and `nil` as falsey (valid in Clojure).

```
(defn ?[t c](every? #(#{"#""+"(% 0)}(% 1))(apply #(map vector % %2)(map #(re-seq #"[^/]+" %) [t c]))))
```

[107](https://tio.run/##lZLtasIwFIb/9yoOKUJCcZ29AHsh4iCmpzWuSerJUZCxa3fxA7HMbS4/DuHkOR95eU0fNjvCo/QR3Jb5hTGyOsoGWw/1gsEs5XQ@v1ycHiCXhNOIW8jF4q1cFgImSkk9DP1BDprY6h5O3B4NB0pPuEc61Kku/xC5EIWQE3hVnynO1OmcZ4EhyzMQ7rAODsuOws43bR8ClUXJ6AYkzWlPobIzHnerTZxlAItHJb3dW58SwY1qE/6Ifrds1uifQe8ar8h2a/YY4z3cWor85xKdJt2NO7dkm5S6J5cqy7KbOBWIYlSRj7So/q/Fr2KMv/fkyqULKcQBjW2tSWJg38TRqKf0udErHdGh59IE8kjf1JEDWc@9h6sza5hcjKSuBlHqR6a6MlVy4Bc) [102](https://tio.run/##lZPRboIwFIbveYqTMhIasjGBex/EaFLLAau0xbaYmGXP7qoSZ6dzjoteHL7z9/DlwDu9HgweUmVBbp17c2gdjQ5pjY2C6cwBn6e4Q7OfQpzGHyQmJCNpAu/0058TSlPW993ev5Sshx1ypw0kkBT0VIhTg68WtxCT2SKfZwQSCqdU6p9DdLwHuBFuAkTuV1pi3ho9qLrptDZ5ljuUPRrm/JCEnnE7LNd2EgHM7rV0YieUL2gZ9Hr8Hr0Rjq9QPYNeBS@NaFdOobXXcCOMdX8O0TLD2jC5MaL2pWtyTqPoW04BJAs64sBF8X8XD2WEn/fkyLnU/rA9ctEI7mVgV9vgqqf8XOglsyhRuZxro9Dc2LnIKY9yNiheVizPAi/l2ctg/Twj0LHjgocB1RiwuAmowoDFj4DeCOU6BeOmT/3en1aZjitK6a9MMTLFA6YcmfIBU41M5X@mLw) working
[91](https://tio.run/##lZLhSsMwFIX/9ykuKUJCcWF9gT3InJClt21mk9SbO0HUZ5@ZHWPFqRNCCOE7JzeHY4e42xMeZEjgn5kXjInVQTbYBlitGexGEt57w7bHdDyOhhkpSDspF4nJhU4TjoOxCBZKUb4/VOJNlEIsKiHyWj/qTSU@lGI1eYMlx0sQ/rWPHnVHcR@adoiRdKUZ/YhkOLsLVXzhab/dpWUBsL4mGdxLHoFi9DNtxq/RT@74l3ALemG8Jdf1HDClS7h1lPjPITpDpps7t@SafHVJblRRFOdwahDVTFHOsqj/n8WvYcy/d@PI2se8pRGta53NYeDQpNlTN@VzprcmocfA2kYKSN/SkWOuGg8BpDcjlHIFd1OR1KkgSv3I1Cemzg38BA) [76](https://tio.run/##lZLdasMwDEbv8xTGYWAT1tC8QB8kzcB1lNSd/yqrgzL27J27ltKwbstujBFH8ueDtA27A8JJ@MTcnmhBkEieRA@DZ6uWmO4EwrNTpLeQzteoiAC9UDHaI0uEuRit0vC@Lvmi4uuKty91V/EPLaUkeRnGNBpaMu6O2@CgHjEcfD/YELCuagIXARXlIFwWX3g6bHZpWTDWPmqx5s34XAhu0pvxR/SrOYf3c9C7wRs045Y8pHQPDwYT/RliVKjG6eQBTZ9L92Qni6K4yWkYryYd5cRF838Xv8qYfm9m5NqFfKQI2gxGZxlg@zR5apafG71RCRx4qnVAD/jNjohoPFnPhFORlWLFni6LJK8LIuWPTHNlmryBnw) [65](https://tio.run/##lZLdasMwDEbv8xTGIWAT1tC8QB@k7cB1lNSd/yargzL27JnLwpawbutujBFH8ueDtA2nM8IofGLumWhFkEgWooOebdhYCoQHp0gfIV2vUREBeqFitBeWCHMxWqXhdVfyVc13Nd8@Nvuav1WtlLKS4zRLo6E14@5yDA6aAcPZd70NAZu6IXARUFHOwSc8nQ@ntC4Y295qsebF@FwIbtGb8Vv0k7nG9/egs8EHNMORPKQ0h3uDif4MMShUw3Jyj6bLpTm5l0XxJadlvF50lAsX7f9d/Cpj@b07Izcu5CNF0KY3OssA26XFU3f5@aQPKoEDT40O6AG/2RERjSfrmXAqslJsWPWxSHJaECl/ZNqJyWs4vgM) all defeated with regex chars

Comment: ...and my comment under your question [becomes pertinent](https://tio.run/##TY7dasMwDIXv8xRCJmATWm97gOZBQgZeqrYp/qusBMLYs7fu1ovpQghJ53xn8um6MN11LBBuInuhIuauj3SK0A8C06h3h8PfEFwGpZl2hW6gcPi0Y4fQGqNdzn7T2bHMzsPzb6VJEtcTrcRbX3XqGxVih7qFN/NT@7t51i8LyvJ1LR8NwICdDdslBbJnTks8nnxKbP28zrEuUrBCIRM7qbFxNE2jM89RfIRXvh5aqCb/1QrNi1B5Dw)

Comment: @JonathanAllan, indeed, except + and # do not appear in subject topic strings :)

Comment: I think this fails for subject `music/kei$ha/latest` and criteria `+/kei$ha/+` (which should match and is valid ASCII).

Comment: @ChasBrown, correct, and with ^ instead of $; thanks.

Comment: Try with '\Q' before and '\E' after the pattern prior to the replace - [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19285125/4089605)

Answer (score 1):

### Python 3, <s>99</s> 88 bytes

Without using a regex.
With some help from Jonathan Allan and Chas Brown.

```
f=lambda s,p:p in(s,'#')or p[:1]in(s[:1],'+')and f(s[1:],p['+'!=p[:1]or(s[:1]in'/')*2:])
```

Comment: `f=lambda s,p:s==p or'#'==p[0]or p[0]in(s[0]+'+')and f(s[1:],p['+'!=p[0]or(s[0]=='/')*2:])` saves 12. However this fails to process some edge cases like `f('abc/ijk/x', 'abc/+/xyz')` or `f('abc/ijk/xyz', 'abc/+/x')`, which can be fixed with `f=lambda s,p:s==p or'#'==p[:1]or p[:1]in(s[:1]+'+')and f(s[1:],p['+'!=p[:1]or(s[:1]=='/')*2:])`

Comment: This fails for `f('abc','ab')` and `f('abc/de','abc')` (both should return `False`, but instead there's an `IndexError`).

Comment: `...or p[:1]in(s[:1],'+')and...` fixes the edge cases @ChasBrown and I pointed out for a cost of 2 bytes.

Comment: Fails another edge case of a trailing '+' (e.g. `f('a/b', 'a/+')`) but fixable in 0 bytes with `...or(s[:1]in'/')*2:])`.

Comment: [Try it online](https://tio.run/##hVCxboMwFJzDV7hieHGDaqXdkFi7dOiQpRJlMMYGt2BbtlMpX08fQUhBCu0E7@7e3fm5S@yseRlHVfR8qBtOQuZyR7TZhwxSoNYTV@bHagKmbwYHoNw0ROF8zKvMlYg8FFeR9bOoKIABfXzOKzqeCgAYLp0dJGu9PZtG9dZ61usfbRCwA4tycNLzePYyuaP81lF00vwnuzGsvW67aGQIi1BpH@KfwS33vF07Kq8bhO7k1jzIQZrIhPVG@lsJvvYpuF7HPXwaoEnSSEVe8ZqC5sR5beK@hA8CGYH3N6hKdaWqjASaKLy2wNuT8t7FDqsY3D@s6BSqPNnNCUCmAEGT3WQZJstTPpdYJNjsRgu8xq4pFsU/sczzxBp5BQQiG7vYTaplgYkGJ9Z2TH9tsSt8yxSV6bbpzI6/) is always recommended!

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>85</s> <s>84</s> <s>80</s> <s>92</s> 89 bytes

```python
lambda s,c:all(x in('+','#',y)for x,y in zip(c.split('/')+[0]*-c.find('#'),s.split('/')))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hZC9bsMgFIXn8hRIGa6paag6WsqapUOHLJUcDxiDTWuDBaSK@/Iuzo9kS247Ie75OOdy@iE01ryManccW96VFceeioy3bXLG2iSQAoUN0IEo6/CZDnGIv3WfiK3vWx0SYEDS/Ll4fBJbpU2VRJpQP1MJGQ87AOiGxnaS1c6eTKVaax1r9Zc2cWA7FmTXS8fDyUm0Qn7qIBpp/sNmhqXTdROM9P4OKu18@DO45o7XS0fldBVHK7kl97KTJjBhnZFujsTf3gs4GiAIVVLhfRKbJRnunTYB5/COgWJ4e4UiVxepoNijqWYxlZyvFZYuUuLzdCFvoMjQwzUA8OQv0MPk6CfHQ3Zd4UYgNAOBl4D2STzE9ULQKhQ3kOpGMlHFC6sbpj9mIpmri/m6Y@Q2vzpeRDL@AA)

Thanks to [Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53748/jonathan-allan) and [Value Ink](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52194/value-ink) for pointing out bugs.

Comment: Gives the wrong answer on `f('ab', 'abc')`.

Comment: @Jonathan Allan: Actually, rules say 'Number of subject fields >= number of criteria fields'. But other problems needed fixing...

Comment: Oh weird rule given the problem context!

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, <s>76</s> <s>73</s> <s>71</s> 67 bytes

```
(a:b)#(c:d)=a=='+'&&b#snd(span(/='/')d)||a=='#'||a==c&&b#d
a#b=a==b
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZHBasQgEIbveQqJZZOQg/eFvEFvfYJRJ4ls1DCahcK@e6qFQtPulrTNRZnx92Pm/0cIF5ymda3hLBteq7NuOui6qq1OJ8mD03WYwdWiq0TV6OZ2y4@8er9VlugCuMxf5GrBONYx7VnB2EzGRfbESvs6eotiIL843U/ek2hFRDsjQVwIS8bviiZzNS41vN2oj0BfTFQjusO5n0aWZIYxOgzhz@TeUIjHejEAwbAV9WR0aj3Cthsx/0dYO0kf2Tww8B5l11bC@nSEGZXpjUrm4qTD3gF/F8UPIAkBLboolCeH9A2xxJdIz46VX4EpzDGjMgtSKVOpyqJY3wA)

Edit: -4 bytes thanks to @cole.

Comment: `a#b=a==b` seems to work for a few bytes fewer, unless I’m missing something

Comment: @cole: yes, that works. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 106 bytes

```
fun f(s:List<String>)=s[1].split("/").filterIndexed{i,v->v!="+"&&v!="#"&&v!=s[0].split("/")[i]}.count()==0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rY5Pa8IwGMbPzafIokiC2rirrMKOg922m/OQtUl9WZqUN2k3kX72Ljo2FDzu8j7w8nv@fPhowY2j6Rw1PKyfIcSHl4jg6o0owvZ@l4fWQuRMMpEbsFHjk6v0l66OsOiXm/6uYHM2m5108qNhu7p0bWE35KXvXOSiKFbnqkaB42pNHxHV4a@PHgnJjEfKOSyowlpQcFTlnxD351IuTkxGsqxNjmgdZ686RDoFuqTTo@HJ89v85pgQAxMpciBkGEep5LssSZK5LMfmsPeNljWmYZWx3qO00KcZ6H0jo25ajSp2qMkNsgJ3gxxrhaq@Jg1ClV4XlGx8OqHVJRgopQFtq0DmV67aWjn5v7jJNw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>22</s> 19 bytes

```
ḟ”+ṣ”/)ZẠƇṖœi”#$¿ZE
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjvmPGuZqP9y5GEjpa0Y93LXgWPvDndOOTs4ECiirHNof5frf2/pRwxwFXTsFoJD14Xauh7u36DxqWvNwxyKVw@1ARiTX0ckgExr3Hdp2aBtE6P//3MqM/NxU/fSi/NK8lLSc/PwifW39ktTcgtSixJLSolQuLApyMssy84AC@bmEVGZnliRnpOaRYGBSUWZ6RkleanExTGFaZlFxCV6L0xOLEtNRTUwrykwBCiGr4tJGUaFMHZ8huZcoZ@jn5gOJ4oLU5My0zGSg51JzUkjwKlRhUmJxam5qXol@cn5RXmoRshIA)

A monadic link that takes as its argument `[topic], [criterion]` and returns `1` for a match and `0` for no match.

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 36 bytes

```
≔⪪Ｓ/θ≔⪪Ｓ/ηＦ∧№η#⊟η≔…θＬηθＦ⌕Ａη+§≔θι+⁼θη
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hY5BCoMwEEX3nkJ0k6DFA7gSaUHoQvAEotEExkyMo9TTp1FLoatuZjHvz5vfydZ22IJzxbKoUbPGgCJWabNSQ1bpkfE0jLLIz5nnwf@U9KkBbcgK3bMSV01MehYfrEbDJOc8/GjKvQNRSr@d0/Ap9Ejy4NerU/JQui8ATkUSfS8LqnQvXseZukge1L4Hsfu8trAcwIty56Zd4iSy0fom/QCINgO1@cYWccpITEbYllYrguQnFLvbBm8) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs `-` (Charcoal's implicit output for `true`) for a match, nothing for no match. Explanation:

```
≔⪪Ｓ/θ
```

Split the subject on `/`s.

```
≔⪪Ｓ/η
```

Split the criteria on `/`s.

```
Ｆ∧№η#⊟η≔…θＬηθ
```

If the criteria contains (i.e. ends with) a `#` then remove it and trim the subject to the new length of the criteria.

```
Ｆ⌕Ａη+§≔θι+
```

Where the criteria contains `+` then replace that element in the subject with `+`.

```
⁼θη
```

Compare the subject with the criteria and implicitly print the result.

Answer (score 0):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 42 bytes

```
%`$
/
+`^([^/]+/)(.*¶)(\1|\+/)
$2
^¶$|¶#/$
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P9fNUGFS59LOyFOIzpOP1ZbX1NDT@vQNk2NGMOaGCCPS8WIK@7QNpWaQ9uU9VX@/8@tzMjPTdVPL8ovzUtJy8nPL9LPySzLzAMK5Ofql6TmFqQWJZaUFqVyaaMoUgYA) Explanation:

```
%`$
/
```

Suffix a `/` to both lines.

```
+`^([^/]+/)(.*¶)(\1|\+/)
$2
```

Repeatedly remove the first element of both subject and criteria while they equal or the criteria element is a (happy) `+`.

```
^¶$|¶#/$
```

The criteria matches if it's just a `#` (with the `/` that was added earlier) otherwise both subject and criteria should be empty by this point.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 22 bytes

```
:Q::E"[+]""[^/]+"\#".*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/3yrQyspVKVo7VkkpOk4/VlspRllJT@v/f6Xcyoz83FT99KL80ryUtJz8/CL9nMyyzDygQH6ufklqbkFqUWJJaVGqEhc2tdooSgA)

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, <s>69</s> 66 bytes

```javascript
t=>s=>new RegExp(s.split`+`.join`[^/]+`.split`#`.join`.+`).test(t)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##tZDBasMwEETP8VcYcoiFW/vaS3LrD/QaUqzIK1mJpBWrjdt@vWtwDnYJ1BR6WZbh7TIzF9nLpMhGfu5fBr0feH9I@0OAj/wNzOtnLFKVorPclE11QRua43t9GvdJ3N7FqmxExZC4YDFopIIxWpWjzo/ZZue/OvRQG8JbaLVDpNrZ3oZRQF8z@Agk@Uawe3pMXy2rDsIadPb4TNZ0HCClOawtJf7VhJEkzfKzJtuO0pzMTiLbKAwJHVQOTZHrKbkoHnkrF8ciF1n2f139SL8qUO1xHCmCstqqsSpw7R/Ku8NnmcBD4FohBaDVzZULl9upqOEb)

Comment: This fails for subject `music/kei$ha/latest` and criteria `+/kei$ha/+` (which should match and is valid ASCII).

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>149</s> 148 bytes

```python
def f(t,c):t,c=t.split('/'),c.split('/');return all([c[i]=='+'or c[i]==t[i]or c[i]=='#'for i in range(len(c))])and not(len(c)!=len(t)and c[-1]!='#')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVTNbqQwDD5PniKllSCClp3ZW1ecVton2BvKIRMMRA0JcsxKffrZ0M6MoELqtBJy8M9nfbZsj6/Ue/fzdGqg5W1GhRbPUVT0FEZrKEvLVBR6ofxCoAkdV9Zmta6NrKo0Tz3y93@K8qqk92kbFcON46hcB5kFl2khpFCu4c7T2XBXzS@9WXX9uJd3M1acNBoCNGrPK54Mr70foOzQT65prfdY5iXBMAKqSAkSdgk/zOH5KvI@YYwg0G8VIER3zXZ1lqijTgoen0QU/I@yAWSxdujZ8xenhaNsYOFbojYYWvPPuGjww4pqwa@lrfNvpHgxpHtw38YvKBzRdD05COFDho0qWoOBvlDEMkWnUHVrFi2aJppuw3@nkYebG7nZhQ/wmyooBx9FGEGb1ujYMbBN@JTSVxp72G7MMU7xAI5K7dEB3gqeQmT5AuahV6VV8zrMg5xfTPli1iVjCGGy9LYsks17fNmfeZ2vu/TMdn6icaIYF@/H2Vz/kPEr@FLfS8F256R5Vb@j4sW4hOylZCMaR9l8W86BQpz@Aw)

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 21 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ε'/¡}ζʒ'+å≠}˜'#¡н2ôøË
```

Input as a list in the order `[criteria, topic]`.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3FZ1/UMLa89tOzVJXfvw0kedC2pPz1FXPrTwwl6jw1sO7zjc/f9/tJK2vrZ@WlFmSnqqfnFqcn5eSnxKUWJ5apG@spKOglJ6YlEiUCa9KL80LyUtJz@/CLviktTcgtSixJLSolT93HwgUVyQmpyZlpmsn5aZmpNSrBQLAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##rZGxTsMwEIZ3nqJykTok6CRGlgo2Jh6gqsBxLonVxI5sp6VIfQDExsxAB94AKhaWZgOp4hl4keCGViIQ1ABdTudP//26@y019TgWQ3Is0szsGZlydtAi3fGZu7NiKTUGlVhSy04yY2EpKRYPHZhPJ4vZ83XHye/eLm8nLzed9nz6@rSf3@eP@VXhzmfdotcj1COuLYz03VavbOqe4OMHScaRTBBCJTPhB7GUChwwmKSoqMkUErdVp4n5kAsLZFIR/8dywA2LUGzN79OKnuJhZARq/WvHgCtttnNzSBUNq5pAcd@ib3ZORdX@wyc0c1hn/jWgmulG20MibdEpMh5wZsPD2NebFmoY8c8GHtWYoDDApBKo6kYHyHcjCk45lWm724rE1KA2a5mzvkkjk8I/9RUd4cYAquKmcThwCEdLa3IB47I/hxEMISP9/js).

**Explanation:**

```python
ε                      # Map both strings in the implicit input-list to:
 '/¡                  '#  Split the string on "/"
                       #   i.e. ["+/+/A/B/#","z/y/A/B/x/w/v/u"]
                       #    → [["+","+","A","B","#"],["z","y","A","B","x","w","v","u"]]
    }ζ                 # After the map: zip/transpose the two string-lists,
                       # with space as (default) filler
                       #  → [["+","z"],["+","y"],["A","A"],["B","B"],["#","x"],[" ","w"],
                       #     [" ","v"],[" ","u"]]
      ʒ    }           # Filter each pair by:
       '+å≠           '#  Only keep those which do NOT contain a "+"
                       #   → [["A","A"],["B","B"],["#","x"],[" ","w"],[" ","v"],[" ","u"]]
            ˜          # Flatten the filtered list
                       #  → ["A","A","B","B","#","x"," ","w"," ","v"," ","u"]
             '#¡      '# Split the list by "#"
                       #  → [["A","A","B","B"],["x"," ","w"," ","v"," ","u"]]
                н      # Only keep the first part
                       #  → ["A","A","B","B"]
                 2ô    # Split this back into pairs of two
                       #  → [["A","A"],["B","B"]]
                   ø   # Zip/transpose them back
                       #  → [["A","B"],["A","B"]]
                    Ë  # And check if both inner lists are equal
                       #  → 1 (truthy)
                       # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```